# How to select from a table where column not exists in another table

Tags: mysql

table A

```
id    city  
1    koronadal  
2    cebu  
3    manila
```

Table B

```
id    city   
1    cebu
```

Expected ouput:

```
id    city
1    koronadal  
3    manila
```

Here is my query:

```
 Select a.id, a.city from tablea a left join tableb b on a.city = b.city
```

I get the wrong output.. please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way! now you just need to filter those who match :

```
Select a.id, a.city
from tablea a
left join tableb b 
 on a.city = b.city
WHERE b.id is null
```

In `LEFT JOINING` when there is no match of the join condition, the left table, in this case tableA will still be selected, and all the data from the right table, in this case tableB will be `NULL` . So all you need to do is search for null values on B table.

Another approach would be to use `IN()` :

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
WHERE a.city NOT IN(SELECT city FROM TableB)
```

And another way is `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB b
                 WHERE a.city = b.city)
```